# Upload a local file to blob container by Shell command

Tags: azure, containers, azure-cli, azure-static-web-app, azure-static-website-hosting

az storage blob upload-batch -d "$web" -s

When I run this command I encounter an error " **argument --source/-s: expected one argument** "

What would I add here? For the source how can I get the path-to-directory ?

I have tried this command "az storage blob upload-batch -d "$web" -s /home/cloud/index.html"

Comment: Did you quote the string correctly  ? like `az storage blob upload-batch -d "$web" -s "/home/cloud/index.html"` Check some examples https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-blob-upload-batch-examples

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Jayendran, You can use this command:

`az storage blob upload-batch -d mycontainer --account-name mystorageaccount --account-key 00000000 -s <path-to-directory>`

make sure to use you are mentioning the file path of the file in quote
like this `"/home/cloud/index.html"

Comment: If you find another answer useful, upvote it and leave comment instead of adding another answer.

Answer (score 0):

> What should I add here? For the source, how can I get the path-to-directory?

**`az storage blob upload-batch`** command is used to upload multiple files to Azure blob storage.

**Command:**

```
az storage blob upload-batch -d <Your-container-name> --account-name <Your-account-name> --account-key "<Your-storage-account-key>" -s "/home/cloud/"
```

You need to mention the path up to the directory only in the source parameter.

**Output:**

In my environment, the above command was executed and uploaded multiple files to the Azure blob storage.

```
PS /home/xxx> az storage blob upload-batch -d xxx --account-name xxx --account-key xxxxx -s "/home/xxxx/dxxx"
The behavior of this command has been altered by the following extension: storage-blob-preview
Finished[#############################################################]  100.0000%
[
  {
    "Blob": "https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/",
    "Last Modified": "2024-01-05T06:33:43+00:00",
    "Type": "application/pdf",
    "eTag": "\"0x8DC0DB84344DF01\""
  },
  {
    "Blob": "https://xxxx.blob.core.windows.net/",
    "Last Modified": "2024-01-05T06:33:43+00:00",
    "Type": "text/plain",
    "eTag": "\"0x8DC0DB8436A89F2\""
  },
  {
    "Blob": "https://xxxx.blob.core.windows.net/",
    "Last Modified": "2024-01-05T06:33:43+00:00",
    "Type": "text/csv",
    "eTag": "\"0x8DC0DB84390D102\""
  },
  {
    "Blob": "https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/",
    "Last Modified": "2024-01-05T06:33:44+00:00",
    "Type": "text/csv",
    "eTag": "\"0x8DC0DB843B20FD1\""
  },
  {
    "Blob": "https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/",
    "Last Modified": "2024-01-05T06:33:44+00:00",
    "Type": "text/csv",
    "eTag": "\"0x8DC0DB843D34E8D\""
  },
  {
    "Blob": "https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/",
    "Last Modified": "2024-01-05T06:33:47+00:00",
    "Type": "video/mp4",
    "eTag": "\"0x8DC0DB84572911F\""
  }
```

[image]

**Portal:**
[image]

If you need to upload a particular blob, you can simply use the below command.

**Command and output:**

```
PS /home/xxxx/demo> az storage blob upload --account-name xxx --account-key xxx --container-name xxx --file "/home/xxxx/demo/sample.txt" --name "demo.txt"
The behavior of this command has been altered by the following extension: storage-blob-preview
Finished[#############################################################]  100.0000%
{
  "client_request_id": "91xxx",
  "content_md5": "xxx",
  "date": "2024-01-05T06:42:18+00:00",
  "encryption_key_sha256": null,
  "encryption_scope": null,
  "etag": "\"0x8DC0DB97664024D\"",
  "last_modified": "2024-01-05T06:42:18+00:00",
  "request_id": "xxxx",
  "request_server_encrypted": true,
  "version": "2020-10-02",
  "version_id": "2xxx"
}
```

[image]

**Portal:**
[image]

Comment: Yeah, I have added my account name then came out successfully..Thanks.